# Managing Inactive SQS Queues in Django with Celery on AWS ECS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-sqs

I have Django app where I am using SQS and celery. Everything is hosted on ECS where I have 3 services: django-api, celery-beat and celery-worker. I have enabled autoscaling policy on celery-worker service that is creating containers/task based on number of MessagesVisible on SQS, by default there are 0 containers in this service.

The problem is that after 6 hours my alarms and SQS are becomming inactive and I need to wait 10-15 minutes to run first celery during a day. It seems that this is some kind of optimization done automatically by AWS. You can read more about that here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-monitoring-using-cloudwatch.html

I was thinking to send empty message to SQS every hour to avoid going to inactive but I don't want to create periodic task because that will trigger my alarm and it will create new container on celery-worker service to perform this task and that will cost me money.

The question is what is the most efficient way to handle this issue without using celery worker? Is there any way to directly send empty message to SQS from Django every hour?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the easiest solution is using a lambda function to send a message every 6 hours?

Comment: @DNy but how to send message to SQS that is invisible for celery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that could work is to run two processes inside ECS, which is generally not recommended. But as you want to optimise more on resources, you can install crontab and keep running that in the background while still keeping django as the main process. You may try one of the following:

1. Use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) process manager and run it in the foreground with django and cron(with `-f` to run it foreground) as child processes. If you don't want to introduce an additional dependency, you can follow the second approcach.
2. Run cron in the background and use shell exec to start django process with PID 1 for proper signal handling. Always use exec form when using bash scripts to avoid unexpected problems with POSIX signals. You can read more about the problem [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8916785). You can additionally use [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) inside the entrypoint to be more safer.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10.8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install cron -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get clean
COPY . .
COPY ./add_sqs_6_hour_cronjob /tmp/cronjob
ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
```

```
#!/bin/bash
crontab /tmp/cronjob
cron
exec "python manage.py runserver"
```